# Left() not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

When i used the LEFT() to fetch the values from database using the following code

```
$select="SELECT LEFT(description,500) FROM tbl_news where id='$id'";
$quer=mysqli_query($select);
$fetch=mysqli_fetch_array($quer);
$descr=$fetch['description'];

echo $descr;
```

The value is not echoing... Is the LEFT() didn't work inside while loop??

Comment: Apart from below answer you can also try `echo $fetch['LEFT(description,500)'];` . Just another way ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

supply an `ALIAS` on the column pass on the function.

```
$select="SELECT LEFT(description,500) description FROM tbl_news where id='$id'";
```

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*) of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)